# Is it enough to prove that the Kernel matrix is positive semidefinite to know that the function is a kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

Is it enough to prove that the Kernel matrix is positive semidefinite to know that the function is a kernel? Or is it also necessary to prove that the matrix is symmetric?

Comment: Because "kernel" has *so many* distinct but related meanings, please give us some context or a clear definition of what you are trying to ask about.

Answer (score 4):

The kernel matrix will always be a symmetric (semi-) definite matrix because it gives the covariances of the images of the data points in the induced feature space, and covariance matrices must be symmetric.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit under-specified -- is it enough *for what purpose*?

The "kernel trick," which OP has included as a tag, is premised on Mercer kernels. Mercer's theorem considers symmetric PSD kernels.